# How to compare wild type and mutant group (n=3) across distance - which statistical test?

Tags: paired-data

I am comparing the p-Erk intensity of wild type (n=3) and mutant (n=3) group around the PSPB region in the developing mouse brain. I have collected intensity data throughout a line drawn across the area of interest, I have made the X axis into 12 bins, each bin is the sum of the intensity within the bin.

The control and mutant embryos are paired, as the sections are placed next to each other on the slide, though they are not the same embryo. (Is this acceptable?)

I have previously conducted a paired t test between the overall wild type and mutant intensity, and it is non-significant.
I thought that this may be due to the bins (X axis) not being paired. So I want to compare the wild type and mutant embryos through comparing the paired bins.
I cannot find a suitable statistical test for this.

Please advise. Thank you!

[image]